# Vibration at speeds between 40-47mph

Tags: tires, suspension, vibration

I went on a road trip of about 870 miles. I hit a speed bump at night because I couldn't see it due to absence of road lights. I applied brakes aggressively as soon as I saw the speed bump and I think the vehicle speed was about 25 mph when it hit the bump.

After the incident, the front tires of the vehicle started bouncing (minor bounce, not severe) between speed range of 40 mph - 47 mph. The bounce goes away after this speed range.

I will be traveling back after couple of weeks but I am worried whether this is a serious issue or not. I am in a remote area right now and I am thinking whether to get the vehicle checked by a mechanic on my way back in some city.

Comment: Get it checked. I have hit a speed bump at 40+mph... no damage and, for once, the suspension moved on my Landrover...

Comment: @SolarMike I bet you didn’t know it *could* move...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Hitting a bump at speed can cause several problems:

- Tire or wheel damage: generally this requires a replacement tire or wheel
- Suspension damage: a suspension member could have been bent or damaged by the impact
- Alignment problems: this isn't damage, just needs a re-alignment
- Lost wheel balancing weights: this is easily fixed by getting the wheels re-balanced

There's no way to be sure which it is without taking it to a mechanic. The first 2 are potentially dangerous, you don't want a tire disintegrating on you or a ball joint failing at speed. Alignment problems aren't generally hazardous unless they are really bad, but they can lead to tires being prematurely worn. A tire out of balance you can live with, but do you really want to drive 870 miles with an annoying vibration?

You have to get it fixed either where you are or when you get back, getting it fixed now is the safest and most sensible option.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will get it checked then before starting the return trip.

Comment: If you're out of time and have to drive on, simply keep your speed below that where the vibration starts.   Avoid trying to push-through to get beyond the vibration zone.  This may mean a slower trip back, so take a scenic route not a highway/motorway.  And console yourself that 40 mph in top gear is using less fuel than 50 mph in the same gear for the same distance.

Comment: I'm guessing that a lost wheel weight is the most likely cause.  But it would be wise to inspect the wheels for any obvious signs of damage.

Comment: 870 miles at 35mph is going to take a looong time @Criggie.

Comment: @GdD true - still beats walking :)

Comment: Not if a ball joint or suspension member fails @Criggie.

Comment: I know this question is old but I would like to update what happened afterwards.
The first thing I did was got the wheel alignment checked and the problem didn't got away. Then I went for wheel balancing and found tires were not perfectly circular. They got damaged after hitting the bump. I came back to my city with those tires safely and replaced them with new soft tires because previously I was using hard tires for puncture resistance purposes.

Comment: Good to know it's resolfed @ifadey, thanks for updating.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably check your tires as it is one of the reasons why you feel a vibration when driving your car.